# Understanding proof of "Uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a strictly increasing sequence"

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis, elementary-set-theory

I read the proof of this theorem in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3826316/proving-that-an-uncountable-subset-of-mathbbr-has-an-strictly-increasing-se), but I am having hard time understanding the answers. What we need to show is that there exists $x \in A$ such that $A \cap (x, \infty)$ is uncountable. But the answers seemingly state (1) there exists $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $A \cap (x, \infty)$ is uncountable (which is quite obvious), and concludes that (2) there exists $x \in A$ such that $A \cap (x, \infty)$ is uncountable. But how exactly does one conclude (2) from (1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $(1)$, there is a $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $A \cap (m, \infty)$ is uncountable. Take $\alpha = \inf A \cap (m, \infty)$. Then, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a $a_n \in A \cap (m, \infty)$ such that $\alpha \le a_n < \alpha + \frac{1}{n}$. Since $A \cap (\alpha, \infty) = \cup_{n=1}^\infty A \cap (a_n, \infty)$ is uncountable, there is some $n_0$ such that $A \cap (a_{n_0}, \infty)$ is uncountable.

Comment: I don't think this is right. Consider $A = \{1\} \cup (2, 3)$ and $m = 0$. Then $A \cap (m, \infty) = A$ is uncountable. As $\alpha = \inf (A \cap (m, \infty)) = 1$, there is no $a_n \in A$ such that $\alpha < a_n < \alpha + 1/n$.

Comment: Right. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Without having read this other post, here is an argument to conclude (2) for uncountable $A$:
there is a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset A$, which is coinitial in $A$ (i.e. for each $a \in A$ there is some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n \le a$). Then $A = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (A \cap [a_n, \infty[)$. Hence $A \cap [a_n, \infty[$ is uncountable for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: How do you prove that there exists a coinitial sequence in uncountable subset? I've tried to look it up but only found proofs using transfinite recursion, which I am not acquainted with.

Comment: This has nothing to do with uncountable: every non-empty set of the reals has a cointial seqence: If the set is unbounded below, choose $a_n < -n$. Otherwise, let $x$ be its infimum and choose $a_n < x + \frac{1}{n}$.